# Can we keep Jest and Karma unit tests together in same Angular project?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, karma-runner

We want to migrate our unit tests from Karma to Jest in our Angular 7 project. Does anyone know if can we keep Jest and Karma puppeteer tests together, because we have pretty big amount of Karma based unit tests? We have read several manuals about how to migrate from one to another, but they all cover an instant switch with final removal of Karma. We want to migrate incrementally, step by step.

Comment: Did you try anything? I guess you could configure the test discovery of each framework to use e.g. `.test.karma` and `.test.jest` or something to differentiate.

Comment: Hi, yes we've tried to keep several test configs, one for karma (https://pastebin.com/VCjCJxTv), one for jest (https://pastebin.com/8y84vk0b). We configured our jest in package.json (https://pastebin.com/eTr3hHs5). We keep our jest unit tests in files like *.jest.ts

Comment: So what's your *question*? Did that not work? Give a [mre] *in the question*.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response, but I'm starting to think that problem in packages version, cause I've created similar example and everything works fine.